# Quick sort "lomuto" partition algorithm: alternate implementation analysis

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Please consider the quick sort "lomuto partition" scheme from the classic algorithms textbook **Introduction to Algorithms** by *Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest & Stein*.

```
PARTITION(A, p, r)
x = A[r]
i = p - 1
for j = p to r - 1
    if A[j] <= x
        i = i + 1
        exchange A[i] with A[j]
exchange A[i + 1] with A[r]
return i + 1
```

After implementing this algorithm, I found that it did not work properly and at best would be off by 1 element.
I then proceeded to calculate a solution and finally came up with the following C code that works. I have commented in the code as to how the algorithm works.

```
int quickSortPartition(int *array, int beginIndex, int endIndex) // end index = array length - 1.
{
    int pivotIndex = beginIndex; // first element as pivot.
    int pivotValue = array[pivotIndex]; // initial pivot value.
    int i = beginIndex + 1; // start loop with i being 2nd index.
    while(i < endIndex) // loop running until end of array.
    {
        if(array[i] > array[i + 1]) // comparing the 2 elements ahead of pivot.
        {
            swap(array, i, i + 1); // swapping the 2 elements if prev element > next element.
        }
        if(array[i] < pivotValue) // comparing element at pivot index with the next index element.
        {
            swap(array, pivotIndex, i); // swapping if next element is less than element at pivot index.
            ++pivotIndex; // incrementing pivot index by 1 ONLY when swap occurs.
        }
        ++i; // drive loop.
    }
    if(array[pivotIndex] > array[pivotIndex + 1]) // at the very end, compare whether the element to the right of pivot is > element at pivot index.
    {
        swap(array, pivotIndex, pivotIndex + 1); // swapping if next element is less than element at pivot index.
        ++pivotIndex; // incrementing pivot index by 1 ONLY when swap occurs.
    }
    return pivotIndex; // returning new pivot index.
}
```

Is my implementation less efficient than that of the book's so called "lomuto partition"? Sure, they are both O(n), but what about in terms of the number atomic operations like assignments & comparisons in one iteration? Does it make a significant difference in efficiency on large scale cases?
Why did the book's algorithm not work? What piece is it missing?
I would also appreciate advice on how to further streamline my code.

Additional follow-up information:

- I have implemented the book's code in python.

```
def quicksort(A, p, r):
    if p < r:
        q = partition(A, p, r)
        quicksort(A, p, q - 1)
        quicksort(A, q + 1, r)

def partition(A, p, r):
    x = A[r]
    i = p - 1
    for j in range(p, r - 1):
        if A[j] <= x:
            i = i + 1
            A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
    A[i + 1], A[r] = A[r], A[i + 1]
    return i + 1

array = [2, 55, 43, 12, 65, 72, 41, 18, 6]
print(array)
quicksort(array, 0, len(array) - 1)
print(array)
```

The result:

```
unsorted: [2, 55, 43, 12, 65, 72, 41, 18, 6]
sorted: [2, 6, 41, 43, 12, 55, 65, 72, 18]
```

As you can see, the sorting failed.
Also, if I were to use len(array) for the third parameter, there would be an overflow error.

- As for my C code that uses my algorithm and works, this is my header file you may test.

```
#ifndef A1_H
#define A1_H

// am1n

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void printArray(int *array, int arrayLength)
{
    int i = 0;
    --arrayLength;
    for(i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d, ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("%d.\n", array[i]);
}

void swap(int *array, int a, int b)
{
    if(array[a] != array[b])
    {
        int tempValue = array[a];
        array[a] = array[b];
        array[b] = tempValue;
    }
}

int fastSortPartition(int *array, int beginIndex, int endIndex) // end index = array length - 1.
{
    int pivotIndex = beginIndex; // first element as pivot.
    int pivotValue = array[pivotIndex]; // initial pivot value.
    int i = beginIndex + 1; // start loop with i being 2nd index.
    while(i < endIndex) // loop running until end of array.
    {
        if(array[i] > array[i + 1]) // comparing the 2 elements ahead of pivot.
        {
            swap(array, i, i + 1); // swapping the 2 elements if prev element > next element.
        }
        if(array[i] < pivotValue) // comparing element at pivot index with the next index element.
        {
            swap(array, pivotIndex, i); // swapping if next element is less than element at pivot index.
            ++pivotIndex; // incrementing pivot index by 1 ONLY when swap occurs.
        }
        ++i; // drive loop.
    }
    if(array[pivotIndex] > array[pivotIndex + 1]) // at the very end, compare whether the element to the right of pivot is > element at pivot index.
    {
        swap(array, pivotIndex, pivotIndex + 1); // swapping if next element is less than element at pivot index.
        ++pivotIndex; // incrementing pivot index by 1 ONLY when swap occurs.
    }
    return pivotIndex; // returning new pivot index.
}

void fastSort(int *array, int beginIndex, int endIndex)
{
    if(beginIndex < endIndex)
    {
        int pivotIndex = fastSortPartition(array, beginIndex, endIndex);
        fastSort(array, beginIndex, pivotIndex - 1);
        fastSort(array, pivotIndex + 1, endIndex);
    }
}

#endif
```

Comment: With this: _'After implementing this algorithm, I found that it did not work properly'_ you mean you noticed some specific array is not processed correctly – amI right? If so, could you show the fatal array?

Comment: It'd be also nice if you show your implementation.

Comment: This comment is wrong: `// end index = array length - 1.`

Comment: No, this is correct, I have implemented such that the array length is taken in as -1. Since it is forward comparing, there would be overflow on last iteration otherwise.

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. The partitioning routine is usually invoked multiple times on different parts of an array, and only _some_ of those calls include the last item of the array, in which case the comment is true.

Comment: Yes, the partitioning sceme is invoked twice recursively till left index >= right index. The case where you mention it is wrong, the loop condition is already met initially, so the inside while loop code does not execute.

Comment: Referring to the book's code not working, I tested it with multiple arrays. I also came across some SO question where it was mentioned that the code served to only explain a simple case and was therefore not for general use. However, I was unable to figure out why it didn't work.

Comment: The pseudo code shows the sort function but your code shows the partition algorithm. So, I think we'd need to see both. Also, what "didn't work", specifically? How did the algorithm differ from the Lomuto in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Comment: The pseudocode shows the partition algorithm and not the sort algorithm. The sort algorithm is just a partition funciton call and two recursive calls.

Comment: I believe your code didn't work. But I don't believe it was a Lomuto algo. Thousands of programmers learned from the book, chances are negligible you were the first to run into the error. Wnt to convince me? Show your implementation and data.

Comment: The sort algorithm is slightly different for Lomuto vs Hoare, so there could be an off-by-one in it, so we need to see it.

Comment: @CiaPan Okay I will implement it in python and deliver the results shortly. I can't find my file for it, so I am doing it now. Thank you for your help with this matter.

Comment: @CraigEstey I will provide the code shortly. Thanks.

Comment: @CiaPan have added the further code and information to the original question. Please advise.

Comment: @CraigEstey have added the further code and information to the original question. Please advise.

Comment: Ah yes I finally noticed the error. The pseudocode in the book ran the loop **to** end_index - 1, but I implemented it as **till** end_index - 1. It was trivial but gave me a headaches for days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let N be the number of elements in the subarray being processed.
Let L be the number of items that eventually fall into the left part of the array – less than or equal to the pivot in the original algorithm, less than the pivot plus the pivot itself in your code.

Both routines must make N–1 steps through the array and N–1 comparisons to check every element and identify those less than or less-or-equal to the pivot. And the original routine makes exactly that number of comparisons. But your code does twice that much: in every iteration of the loop it compares `array[i]` to `pivotValue` AND `array[i]` to `array[i + 1]`.

Both routines must also make almost exactly L swaps to group those smaller items together, plus up to two swaps for temporarily moving the pivot out of way and back to place. But your code may make up to N–1 additional swaps to push the 'big' elements rightwards with no significant gain.

So the answer is: no, your proposed code certainly is not more efficient than the original algorithm, neither in a number of comparisons nor in a number of swaps.

Your code does about twice as much work (elementary operations) as the Lomuto's method. But that's just a scaling factor; taking things asymptotically they are both linear, O(N).

---

It turns out I was right: your implementation was NOT the Lomuto algorithm – due to incorrect use of `for j in range()` you did not test the last item of the array, as the original routine requires.

Comment: Yes I finally noticed. Due to my inexperience I read the pesudocode run loop **to** as ```<``` where it should have been ```==```.

Comment: Would you kindly offer your thoughts on how you would rate the difficulty of this algorithm based on beginner, moderate or difficult? Is the partition scheme a pattern that most experienced mathematicians could come up with? I ask this because I initially tried to work on the quicksort on my own and found it very difficult. But during my research I came across a Wikipedia article that mentioned that Tony Hoare did not initially publish his algorithm because he thought it was too simple. Kind of an opinion based question, but I was just wondering.

Comment: @mindoverflow IMHO it is very simple – once you learned using _invariants_. An invariant is an expression, whose true value is preserved by the code. This helps us to reason about the code. In this case it is 'the initial segment of the array up to the index `pivotIndex` contains all items less than pivot found between the beginning and `i`'. As 'i' increases we can show by induction that every eligible item gets added to the segment. Once we also prove `i` scans the _whole_ array (which your original code failed to do) we know the routine does what we expect.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable insight. This is the first time I have heard of invariants. Oddly, never came across this during Algorithms Design or Discrete Mathematics! I will look into this further. Once again, thank you.

Comment: @mindoverflow Please see the note I added,   about the big-O estimate of your code vs the Lomuto's one.

Answer (score 1):

Changing upper limit of loop to proper value solves the problem

```
for j in range(p, r):
```

Note that Python range does not include right border, and pivot remains at the end until the end of partition

Result for your example

```
[2, 6, 12, 18, 41, 43, 55, 65, 72]
```